# Как адекватно записать содержимое файла в строку?

Tags: c

Имеется код для записи содержимого файла в строку, зная точный размер содержимого файла (узнается заранее):

```
void read_file(FILE *fd, char *text, int size)
{
    fgets(text, size, fd);
}
```

Далее я посимвольно перебираю и распечатываю строку:

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    printf("%c", text[i]);
}
```

Все в порядке в случае если текст в файле является однострочным. Но как только я добавляю переносы строки, или табуляцию, все ломается. Распечатка символов просто заканчивается на моменте первого переноса строки. Наглядно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем: как я мог бы получать содержимое файла, включая \n, \t и прочие невидимые управляющие комбинации? Есть ли в C возможность читать текст включая эти символы как обычные, доступные к перебору и обращению через string[n]? Файл открыт в бинарном варианте.

Comment: Ну, если точно знаете размер — то `fread`, например — для чтения *всего файла* в буфер. Или читайте и выводите посимвольно..

Comment: @Harry да, кажется это решение работает правильно

Comment: [man 2 read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте читать по одному символу.

```
FILE *fl;
fl = fopen("test.html", "r");
char *str;
str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
unsigned int strsize;
strsize = 128;
char nchar;
unsigned int readed;
readed = 0;
while((nchar = getc(fl)) > 0){
    str[readed] = nchar;
    if(++readed == strsize){
        str = (char*)realloc(str, sizeof(char) * (strsize += 128));
    }
}
puts(str);
```

Файл читается до тех пор, пока `getc` не вернет **-1**. Этот способ хорош тем, что имеется возможность убирать из текста определенные символы: пробелы(32), табы(9) и переносы('\n'), например. Можно читать текст любых размеров. Работает очень быстро.

Comment: EOF не обязан быть меньше нуля. И `getc` возвращает `int` а не char.

Comment: 1) `EOF` обязан быть меньше нуля, но не обязан равняться `-1`. 2) Если в файле есть символы с отрицательными кодами, и тип `char` знаковый, то условие `(nchar = getc(fl)) > 0` выполнится  прежде, чем будет достигнут конец файла. 3) В итоговую строку не добавляется терминирующий нуль. 4) Вызов `realloc(sizeof(char) * (strsize += 128))` вообще не похож на код, который успешно скомпилируется.

Comment: @wololo, поправил.